# TensorFlow - error while converting *.pb file to *.tflite with toco

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I used the following example to create tensorflow model: http://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/training-convolutional-neural-network-for-image-classification/
You can download the code from here: https://github.com/sankit1/cv-tricks.com/tree/master/Tensorflow-tutorials/tutorial-2-image-classifier
Also I used "2. Freezing the graph" section from http://cv-tricks.com/how-to/freeze-tensorflow-models/
to create a *.pb file of my model.
I'm tried to convert *.pb file with toco command line tool, as describe on "Convert a TensorFlow SavedModel to TensorFlow Lite" at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/g3doc/cmdline_examples.md#savedmodel
and got he following error:

(venv) user@user-desktop:~/PycharmProjects/tensorflow_tutorial/tensorflow$ bazel run -c opt tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco:toco -- --savedmodel_directory=/home/user/PycharmProjects/tensorflow_tutorial/tutorial-2-image-classifier --output_file=/home/user/PycharmProjects/tensorflow_tutorial/tutorial-2-image-classifier/dogs-cats-model.tflite
WARNING: /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/e21a56d90e65395c94952f8aa3d0c4bc/external/protobuf_archive/WORKSPACE:1: Workspace name in /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/e21a56d90e65395c94952f8aa3d0c4bc/external/protobuf_archive/WORKSPACE (@com_google_protobuf) does not match the name given in the repository's definition (@protobuf_archive); this will cause a build error in future versions
INFO: Analysed target //tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco:toco (0 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 1 target...
WARNING: failed to create one or more convenience symlinks for prefix 'bazel-':
cannot create symbolic link bazel-out -> /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/e21a56d90e65395c94952f8aa3d0c4bc/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out: /home/user/PycharmProjects/tensorflow_tutorial/tensorflow/bazel-out (File exists)
cannot create symbolic link bazel-out -> /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/e21a56d90e65395c94952f8aa3d0c4bc/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out: /home/user/PycharmProjects/tensorflow_tutorial/tensorflow/bazel-out (File exists)
cannot create symbolic link bazel-tensorflow -> /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/e21a56d90e65395c94952f8aa3d0c4bc/execroot/org_tensorflow: /home/user/PycharmProjects/tensorflow_tutorial/tensorflow/bazel-tensorflow (File exists)
cannot create symbolic link bazel-bin -> /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/e21a56d90e65395c94952f8aa3d0c4bc/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin: /home/user/PycharmProjects/tensorflow_tutorial/tensorflow/bazel-bin (File exists)
cannot create symbolic link bazel-testlogs -> /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/e21a56d90e65395c94952f8aa3d0c4bc/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/testlogs: /home/user/PycharmProjects/tensorflow_tutorial/tensorflow/bazel-testlogs (File exists)
cannot create symbolic link bazel-genfiles -> /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/e21a56d90e65395c94952f8aa3d0c4bc/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles: /home/user/PycharmProjects/tensorflow_tutorial/tensorflow/bazel-genfiles (File exists)
Target //tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco:toco up-to-date:
/home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/e21a56d90e65395c94952f8aa3d0c4bc/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.271s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
INFO: Running command line: /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/e21a56d90e65395c94952f8aa3d0c4bc/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco '--savedmodel_directory=/home/user/PycharmProjects/tensorflow_tutorial/tutorial-2-image-classifier' '--output_file=/home/user/PycharmProjects/tensorflow_tutorial/tutorial-2-image-classifier/dogs-cats-model.tflite'
2018-05-07 01:33:13.776954: F tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco_saved_model.cc:34] **Check failed: tensorflow::MaybeSavedModelDirectory(model_path) Model is not saved in the supported SavedModel format.**

The function which throw this error is MaybeSavedModelDirectory at
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco_saved_model.cc, 
I took a look at the implementation of it on
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc
Actually it looking for *.pb or *.pbtxt file on the model directory and I got this file on requested location, so why I get this error?

Machine details:
OS Platform and Distribution - ubuntu x64,
TensorFlow installed from - pip,
TensorFlow version - cpu version 1.8.0,
Bazel version - 0.13.0,
CUDA/cuDNN version - no cuda,
GPU model and memory - no gpu,
Exact command to reproduce - no need,
python version - 3.5.2

Answer (score 0):

There are two formats that TensorFlow 1.8 supported:

1. [SavedModels](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#using_savedmodel_with_estimators)
2. Frozen GraphDefs generated via [freeze_graph.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py)

In your case, if you have already used freeze_graph.py then you should be following the documentation that refers to GraphDefs. The latest documentation from TensorFlow Lite is available [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/g3doc/cmdline_examples.md#convert-a-tensorflow-graphdef-).

Copied from documentation (of TensorFlow 1.9):

The follow example converts a basic TensorFlow GraphDef (frozen by `freeze_graph.py`) into a TensorFlow Lite FlatBuffer to perform floating-point inference. Frozen graphs contain the variables stored in Checkpoint files as Const ops.

```
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/mobilenet_v1_0.50_128_frozen.tgz \
  | tar xzv -C /tmp
tflite_convert \
  --output_file=/tmp/foo.tflite \
  --graph_def_file=/tmp/mobilenet_v1_0.50_128/frozen_graph.pb \
  --input_arrays=input \
  --output_arrays=MobilenetV1/Predictions/Reshape_1
```

The value for `input_shapes` is automatically determined whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using toco, use Colab to convert your .pb into .lite as mentioned here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58583419/11517841

with explanations as to why this would be more simple.